# Recur not at tail position

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, lisp, tail-recursion

**How can I use something similiar to `recur`not at tail position?**

Take a look at my code:

```lisp
(defn -main [& args]

  (println "Hi! Type a file name...")

  (defn readFile[])
    (let [fileName(read-line)]
    (let [rdr (reader fileName)]
      (if-not (.exists rdr) 
        ((println "Sorry, this file doesn't exists. Type a valid file name...")
         (recur)))
         (defn list '())
         (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
           (if-not (= "" line)
             (concat list '(line)))
             (list))))

(defn fileLinesList (readFile))
  ...
  ...)
```

I know I can't use `recur` here... But I neither know how can I make it in clojure.

I'm a newbie in Clojure and I'm coming from a OOP context. So...

**Is there a way to use recursion in this case?**
**What would be an alternative?**

Comment: Is your goal to write a function reading lines of text from a file or existing function would be good enough for you?

Comment: Well... A function that returns if a file exists already exists. I want to call the `readFile` function until the given file name exists.

Comment: Although you have not written it like this the logic of your function seems to be 'if <file does not exist> then <recurse> else <do things assuming file exists>', in which case the function *is* tail-recursive.  So I'd suggest rewriting it like that.

Comment: There are other mistakes that Piotrek didn't mention, but which his code avoids.  Just to get you started in the right direction: (1) In Clojure, none of the everyday, common functions will actually modify a piece of data, as your line `(concat list '(line))` is supposed to do, since it's inside of a `doseq`.  `concat` cannot modify `list`; instead, it returns a new piece of data, which is the concatenation of its arguments.

Comment: (2) `'(line)` will return a list containing a single element, the symbol `line`, but what you wanted was the contents of that symbol.  What should have been there was `line` without the parentheses or the quote.

Comment: (3) What `(list)` in the last line looks like it returns is the result of calling the function `list` on no arguments, returning the empty list.  When there is an unquoted list, its first argument is normally treated as the name of a function, which is to be evaluated with the other elements of the list as its arguments (except in special cases, as when the list is quoted).  However, in this case, *you have redefined `list`*, so that it no longer refers to a function.  So `(list)` will produce an error rather than executing the function that `list` normally names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should not nest your functions definitions in another `defn` (`-main` in this case). `defn` or `def` always defines symbol bindings at the top level of namespace and they don't nest. If you want to define a locally scoped function you need to use `let` and `fn`, e.g.

```
(let [my-fn (fn [a b] (+ a b))]
  (my-fn 1 2))
```

In your particular case I think it would be easier to split your code into multiple functions. This way it will be more readable.

Prompting for a file name is one piece of your logic.

```
(defn get-existing-filename []
  (let [filename (read-line)]
    (if (.exists (java.io.File. filename))
      filename
      (do
        (println "Sorry, this file doesn't exists. Type a valid file name...")
        (recur)))))
```

Then you can use it to read a file removing empty lines:

```
(with-open [input (clojure.java.io/reader (get-existing-filename))]
  (->> (line-seq input)
       (remove empty?)
       (doall)))
```

For a file with following content:

```
AAA

BBB
CCC

DDD
```

it will return

```
("AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD")
```

If you really want it as a single function, the following will work:

```
(defn read-file []
  (let [filename (read-line)]
    (if (.exists (java.io.File. filename))
      (with-open [input (clojure.java.io/reader (get-existing-filename))]
        (->> (line-seq input)
             (remove empty?)
             (doall)))
      (do
        (println "Sorry, this file doesn't exists. Type a valid file name...")
        (recur)))))
```

Finally, this function can be called from `-main`.

I have also noticed another issue in your sample code:

```
((println "Sorry, this file doesn't exists. Type a valid file name...")
 (recur))
```

`if` and `if-not` require a single expression for their `then` and `else` branches. If you want to have multiple expressions you need to nest them in `do`:

```
(do
  (println "Sorry, this file doesn't exists. Type a valid file name...")
  (recur))
```

If you need `if` or `if-not` without the else branch then you can use `when` or `when-not` macros. Then you don't need to wrap multiple expressions because `when`/`when-not` will wrap them for your inside of `do`.

```
(when true
  (println 1)
  (println 2))
```

is equivalent to

```
(if true
  (do
    (println 1)
    (println 2)))
```